# What does each element do ("(.)\\1{1,}", "$1") in this code?

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class redigetajs {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input text!");
        String teksts= scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("text after change!");
        System.out.println(teksts.replaceAll("(.)\\1{1,}", "$1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `{1,}` is the same as `+`. [Check the SO regex reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618)

Answer (score 3):

It matches sequences of identical characters and collapses them into only one occurrence.

Example: `"aaaaabcccdd"` -> `"abcd"`

Answer (score 1):

Suexpression duplicate a group character and removed:

- `(.)` - group, also referenced as `$1`
- `\\1` - subexpression followed it
- `{1,}` - to repeat one or more times

Comment: What is $1? What happens when replace with $1?

Comment: substitute group match and replace with it

Answer (score 1):

Perfect tool for this:

http://regex101.com/r/kF3uB7

need 30 characters :)